# Request Content-Length 198664571 exceeds the configured limit of 31457280

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ubuntu-16.04, spark-jobserver

While hosting the jar file in spark-jobserver the following error occurs Request Content-Length 198664571 exceeds the configured limit of 31457280 in ubuntu16

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OtOE.png)

I have changed the configuration in onprem.conf and application.conf files

onprem.conf

`spray.can.server { parsing.max-content-length="300m" }`

application.conf

## Increase this in order to upload bigger job jars

`parsing.max-content-length = 300m`

suggest solution for the above error.